# Testing if a converter is applied for a map

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper for model conversions and trying to test whether a converter has been applied for a map or not.

I find the required map using

```
var typemap = mapper.ConfigurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor<TSource, TDestination>();
```

and then assert `typemap.TypeConverterType`

This method is working fine when using `ConvertUsing<TTypeConverter>()` in the maps, but `TypeConverterType` is null when using `ConvertUsing(ITypeConverter<TSource, TDestination> converter)`.

I could not find any converter related information in the TypeMap for this case.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're not testing AM, you're testing your own code. So make a scenario that makes sense for your app and test that. That means testing the whole mapping, not how AM handles your mapping. So feed an input to Map and test the result.